# Rsync - Corrupted MAC on input

Tags: backup, rsync, raspberry-pi, tcp, raspbian

**Background**
I have a script on my NAS which is a Synology DS212J which is running on a special distro where `uname -a` gives me `Linux DS212J 2.6.32.12 #4493 Wed Jul 16 11:37:16 CST 2014 armv5tel GNU/Linux synology_88f6281_212j` which is suppose to run `rsync` to backup my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (based on Debian).

The backup script looks like this

```
/usr/syno/bin/rsync -aEv --ignore-errors --delete --rsync-path="sudo usr/bin/rsync" --exclude-from=/volume1/backup_hdd1/rsync-pi/rsync-exclude.txt -e "ssh -p 22" pi@192.168.0.103:/ /volume1/backup_hdd1/rsync-pi/backup >> /volume1/backup_hdd1/rsync-pi/rpi_backup.log 2>&1
```

**Problem**
The backup script was working until recently when I checked the logs where I'm getting multiple errors but they all can be traced back to these two lines:

```
Corrupted MAC on input.
Disconnecting: Packet corrupt
```

**What I've tried**
Disabled TCP checksum offload by this command

```
ethtool -K eth0 tx off rx off
```

And basically trying everything Google suggest. Sometimes it transfers up to 50 MBs where sometimes it only reaches a few MBs before aborting.

I'm completely lost since it was working flawlessly the other day. Only thing that I've done on the system is update a few programs - nothing major. I've also tried removing these programs but it didn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas or tips of what I can do to get it working again?

Comment: [Do a memory test](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38887/how-can-i-test-the-ram-for-data-corruption-on-an-arm-based-system).

Comment: any luck with this? i have same problem